# serious crashing problem with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I installed ubuntu on my new computer (no other OS) , and it crashes suddenly all the time , There is no program that i specifically use when ubuntu crashes .
When it occurs , I can't move the mouse or do anything , it stops disabling any move but doesn't shut down the computer or show an alert or something like that .

I use Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit .
My computer :
HP Pro , intel i7 processor , ram 8go , nvidia gt520 2Go , 20" HP 2011x LED screen .

Excuse me if I made mistakes , english is my third language .

Please Help .

Comment: When you restart, have a look at var/log/syslog it might show you the error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting into recovery mode?
Press `shift key` when the very first purple screen appear than use check or fix filesystem. Have you tried updating everything ? In the update manager ?
If non of that works try to reinstall ubuntu you could of have an bad install.